# Is there a risk of losing data (Documents and iPhoto) while downgrading to OS X Snow leopard to 10.5 (leopard)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macbook-pro

I was in the middle of re-installing OS X Snow leopard, the system crashed and I thought, there something wrong with my installation DVD (I bought that upgrade version separately and was using it for more than a year) then I tried re-intalling with my original DVD which 10.5 and crashed again, later I realized crashing issue due to my display chip and got it replaced and my display works fine.

After display chip was repaired, I tried reinstalling my current version 10.6 snow leopard. It says "Couldn't be installed as some files couldn't be copied", I think this message is because of installation mess because I am sure my DVD is not damaged it looks very new and scratches.  Now I am wondering if I reinstall my macbook pro with 10.5 DVD will there be a risk of losing my data (Documents and iPhoto) that was under 10.6.

Answer (score 1):

well You should have backups of all your data right?

Assuming you don't do fresh install. and either do an Archive Install or an upgrade, you *should* be fine.

That being said if you don't have a backup of your data, I would make one now.  YOu should be able to boot your mac in target disk mode, and then use that copy all your important stuff off to another mac, before you make any changes..

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1661  for info on target disk mode

Other option is to install OS to external DISK (as opposed to your internal one).  Boot off the external and copy all your data off.  This will minimize risk to losing data on internal drive.

Good luck..